# How could a spring singleton bean could be used for stateless conversations?

Tags: java, spring, scope

Good Morning all.  Today morning when I am going through Spring reference guide I come across the following statement

```
As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton
scope for stateless beans.
```

Context.getBean(...) will always return a newly instantiated object when the bean scope is "prototype".  Then how could we achieve the stateful feature?  How could I maintain the conversation here?

Similarly "singleton" would be created only once per container. So upon multiple requests, it holds the same set of data (i mean last state if we speak more accurate).  Then what does all about the above statement from spring reference document.  I was so confused.  Please help me out in understanding the statement?  I might have a wrong understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In our CRUD application, the Spring DAO is a singleton. That is, only the jdbc template initialization is a class level variable. The other logic is all part of the method call. So, effectively, the state is part of the stack frame and not heap and hence it is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

Imagine that you have a bean - e.g. a service - that holds the state of a complex call (and possibly calls to other components that is used by the service) via some private fields. If two calls occurs at the same time to that bean/service the state is compromised since the member fields can't handle the state of two simultaneous calls. If you want to hold the state for two simultaneous calls you probably need to store the state in some kind of map where the key was e.g. the thread id.

However, if you use a prototype bean a new bean (service in the example) is created for each request/invocation and the state can safely be stored in the bean's private fields since the bean will not be shared among different requests.

Note that if you want to keep the state between several requests (like session state or similar) the way to go is probably to save the state in some kind of *state store* (such as a singleton bean with a Map or even better a cache based on e.g. EhCache).